# Mandelbrot Slicing Image to Improve Speed

Tags: c++

The Mandelbrot set currently displays the image in one whole set by calling the function from the main.

```
// This shows the whole set.
    compute_mandelbrot(-2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125);
```

My plan is to split the image up into 16 horizontal slices and then display it to improve the speed as can then parallel program this in.
**I'm unsure how to create these slices, can someone explain, redirect me or show some example code**

image details:

```
// The size of the image to generate.
const int WIDTH = 100;
const int HEIGHT = 100;

// The number of times to iterate before we assume that a point isn't in the
// Mandelbrot set.

const int MAX_ITERATIONS = 500;
```

For the purpose of testing, ill send the full code, there are no errors - it is not coded efficiently evidently as the whole process takes over 30 seconds to output, which is way too long for a Mandelbrot set, hence the urgency of the slicing and parallel programming.

If anyone has any other pointers then they would be greatly appreciated

e.g. where to implement parallel programming

```
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::complex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ofstream;

// Define the alias "the_clock" for the clock type we're going to use.
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock the_clock;


// The size of the image to generate.
const int WIDTH = 100;
const int HEIGHT = 100;

// The number of times to iterate before we assume that a point isn't in the
// Mandelbrot set.

const int MAX_ITERATIONS = 500;

// The image data.
// Each pixel is represented as 0xRRGGBB.
uint32_t image[HEIGHT][WIDTH];


// Write the image to a TGA file with the given name.
// Format specification: http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake3/TGA.txt
void write_tga(const char *filename)
{
    ofstream outfile(filename, ofstream::binary);

    uint8_t header[18] = {
        0, // no image ID
        0, // no colour map
        2, // uncompressed 24-bit image
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // empty colour map specification
        0, 0, // X origin
        0, 0, // Y origin
        WIDTH & 0xFF, (WIDTH >> 8) & 0xFF, // width
        HEIGHT & 0xFF, (HEIGHT >> 8) & 0xFF, // height
        24, // bits per pixel
        0, // image descriptor
    };
    outfile.write((const char *)header, 18);

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            uint8_t pixel[3] = {
                image[y][x] & 0xFF, // blue channel
                (image[y][x] >> 8) & 0xFF, // green channel
                (image[y][x] >> 16) & 0xFF, // red channel
            };
            outfile.write((const char *)pixel, 3);
        }
    }

    outfile.close();
    if (!outfile)
    {
        // An error has occurred at some point since we opened the file.
        cout << "Error writing to " << filename << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}


// Render the Mandelbrot set into the image array.
// The parameters specify the region on the complex plane to plot.
void compute_mandelbrot(double left, double right, double top, double bottom)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            // Work out the point in the complex plane that
            // corresponds to this pixel in the output image.
            complex<double> c(left + (x * (right - left) / WIDTH),
                top + (y * (bottom - top) / HEIGHT));

            // Start off z at (0, 0).
            complex<double> z(0.0, 0.0);

            // Iterate z = z^2 + c until z moves more than 2 units
            // away from (0, 0), or we've iterated too many times.
            int iterations = 0;
            while (abs(z) < 2.0 && iterations < MAX_ITERATIONS)
            {
                z = (z * z) + c;

                ++iterations;
            }

            /*if (iterations == MAX_ITERATIONS)
            {
                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0x58DC77; // green
            }*/
            if (iterations <= 10)
            {
                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0xA9C3F6; // light blue
            }
            else if (iterations <=100)
            {

                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0x36924B; // darkest green
            }
            else if (iterations <= 200)
            {

                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0x5FB072; // lighter green
            }
            else if (iterations <= 300)
            {
                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0x7CD891; // mint green
            }
            else if (iterations <= 450)
            {
                // z didn't escape from the circle.
                // This point is in the Mandelbrot set.
                image[y][x] = 0x57F97D; // green
            }
            else
            {
                // z escaped within less than MAX_ITERATIONS
                // iterations. This point isn't in the set.
                image[y][x] = 0x58DC77; // light green
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Processing" << endl;

    // Start timing
    the_clock::time_point start = the_clock::now();

    // This shows the whole set.
    compute_mandelbrot(-2.0, 1.0, 1.125, -1.125);

    // This zooms in on an interesting bit of detail.
    //compute_mandelbrot(-0.751085, -0.734975, 0.118378, 0.134488);

    // Stop timing
    the_clock::time_point end = the_clock::now();

    // Compute the difference between the two times in milliseconds
    auto time_taken = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    cout << "Computing the Mandelbrot set took " << time_taken << " ms." << endl;


    write_tga("output.tga");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As for your problem, how much do you know about *threads*? This seems like a job for [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), and you could actually have one `async` for each line of the image if you want, or split it up to X lines per `async`.

Comment: Beginner with threads so knowledge is pretty basic on them. How would I make async cover each line of the image? I just had a read over the page dedicated to it.    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: Thirty seconds?! That program takes around 290 *milli*seconds on my (2.7 GHz) machine, without optimisation. There must be something weird with your setup.

Comment: Sounds like something where you rather want to rethink your algorithm. If it takes 30s serial, the best you can hope for with four cores would be 7.5s, which I assume is still too slow. (Don't know much about computing the Mandelbrot set, but check the internet for heuristics on that one.)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to use N parallel threads for the rendering, then each thread will handle `HEIGHT / N` lines.

For simplicities sake I pick an N that divides your `HEIGHT` evenly, like `5`. That means each thread will handle 20 lines each (with your `HEIGHT` being equal to `100`).

You could implement it something like this:

```
constexpr int THREADS = 5;  // Our "N", divides HEIGHT evenly

void compute_mandelbrot_piece(double left, double right, double top, double bottom, unsigned y_from, unsigned y_to)
{
    for (unsigned y = y_from; y < y_to; ++y)
    {
        for (unsigned x = 0; y < WIDTH; ++x)
        {
            // Existing code to calculate value for y,x
            // ...
        }
    }
}

void compute_mandelbrot(double left, double right, double top, double bottom)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> render_threads;
    render_threads.reserve(THREADS);  // Allocate memory for all threads, keep the size zero

    // Create threads, each handling part of the image
    for (unsigned y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y += HEIGHT / THREADS)
    {
        render_threads.emplace_back(&compute_mandelbrot_piece, left, right, top, bottom, y, y + HEIGHT / THREADS);
    }

    // Wait for the threads to finish, and join them
    for (auto& thread : render_threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    // Now all threads are done, and the image should be fully rendered and ready to save
}
```